# Why am I not mentioned in the “marked as duplicate” label?

Tags: support, duplicates, privileges

Yesterday I flagged [number of loopback addresses](https://askubuntu.com/questions/952759/number-of-loopback-addresses) as a duplicate of [How to add a loopback interface?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444124/how-to-add-a-loopback-interface), and as far as I can tell from the automatic comment I was the first and only one to do so. Now that it's officially marked as duplicate I wonder why I'm not mentioned:

[image: “marked as duplicate” label]

Comment: Because close voters but not flaggers show up in the list.